# Roku https request failed

Tags: ssl, https, roku, brightscript

I have the below code to get data from my `https` website having godaddy certificate.but i unable to get the result from the url.

```
port = CreateObject("roMessagePort")
req = createObject("roUrlTransfer")
req.SetMessagePort(port)
req.setCertificatesFile("pkg:/source/domain.crt")
req.AddHeader("X-Roku-Reserved-Dev-Id", "")
req.InitClientCertificates()
req.setUrl("https://domain.com/index.php/roku/getdata")
response = req.getToString()
print "response: "; response
```

**Note:** i edited `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf` file to add godaddy certificate.in my website,https is working.i alwaise getting error code -77.i exported the crt file from mozilla firefox.is this a correct way?

Answer (score 4):

No idea about the correct format of certificate export. But have you tried:

```
req.SetCertificatesFile("common:/certs/ca-bundle.crt")
```